# Lograr que la imagen de un FrameLayout ocupe toda la pantalla.

Tags: android, android-studio

Cordial saludo,

Estoy diseñando una aplicación Navigation Drawer, el ContentMain lo tengo con una imagen de fondo, mi ideal es que al dar clic en alguna opción aparezca la misma imagen mucho mas atenuada, para ello coloco en el fragment la misma imagen de fondo pero con efecto de trasparencia, pero esta no ocupa toda la pantalla y se pierde el efecto. ¿Como logro que ocupe toda la pantalla y no se vea la imagen normal?

**IMAGEN DEL MAINCONTENT**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**IMAGEN AL DAR CLIC EN ALGUNA OPCION**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `FrameLayout` regularmente no tiene problema, generalmente el layout contenido contiene un margen, el cual se debe eliminar:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="?dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="?dp"
android:layout_marginRight="?dp"
android:layout_marginTop="?dp"
```

No definas margen o define:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
```